# Unable to transition from new state - pending refund details state Rails Statemachine Gem --- Pluginaweek

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

Can't understand via I am getting this error StateMachine::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition state via :refund_details_not_found from :new (Reason(s): State cannot transition via "refund details not found")

```
state_machine :initial => :new do    
    event :all_products_received do
      transition [:new, :pending_refund_details, :canceled] => :pending_payment
    end

event :refund_details_not_found do
  transition :new => :pending_refund_details
end

event :order_return_canceled do
  transition :new => :canceled
end

event :mistaked_canceled do
  transition :canceled => :buyer_dispatched
end

event :payment_made do
  transition :pending_payment => :payment_complete
end

before_transition :to => :canceled do |return1|
  return1.total = 0
end

before_transition :to => :pending_payment do |return1|
  return1.pending_on = Time.now
end

before_transition :to => :payment_complete do |return1|
  return1.completed_on = Time.now
end

end
```

I calling the transition in before save

Comment: Just to clear it up, you're doing `object.refund_details_not_found` and get that error?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and by itself I'm not getting any error:

```
require 'state_machine'

class Thing
  attr_accessor :state

  state_machine :initial => :new do
    event :refund_details_not_found do
      transition :new => :pending_refund_details
    end
  end
end

t = Thing.new
puts t.state
#=> new
t.refund_details_not_found
puts t.state
#=> pending_refund_details
```

I would suggest checking if you have some other element interfering, e.g.: Rails validations, other callbacks or `before_transition`s, superclasses implementing `state_machine` already etc.

Comment: i trying to do this in a before save block. In there some conflict with state machine transition and before save

Comment: In a `before_save` for the same object? I would suggest using the `pry` gem and put a `binding.pry` inside that `before_save` to see what happens.